# Weird Leg Bend In Movie Deaths

Tags: film-techniques, realism

In a lot of films, whenever someone dies, it almost-always shows them lying with one leg bent at almost a 90-degree angle.

Why are the bodies depicted like that? Is this some old rule or an unsaid agreement between directors?

Comment: Some examples might be useful here but this seems a litle unclear. People don't just "fall down" with both legs straight...it's not normal. Legs collapse...what else are you expecting?

Comment: Sadly not always true.  If you have the grim determination to watch the film of the execution of Nguyễn Văn Lém (Vietnam), you'll see that post-shooting, he ends up with arms and legs straight.  It's a nervous system thing and very unsettling and unnatural to watch...

Comment: You should provide some examples of the movies and the scenes. Did the person fall from a height? Was it an auto-accident? These things would help people write a better answer.

Comment: But's the most common "death shot", no? 90-degree bend? I'll try and find some examples.

Comment: @Snow - Watch the R Budd Dwyer suicide video.  That cat definitely doesn't lay straight down.  *side note* - I had no idea that much blood could exit a nose.

Answer (score 2):

It's what audiences expect to see.

They expect the victim to collapse on the floor in a generally untidy state, and stay as they fell.

Lying down neatly with arms and legs straight looks unnatural to most audiences.

However, in real life, the nervous system and muscles do strange and unusual things to the body (depending on the mode of death), and this isn't the kind of realism that audiences typically know about or wish to see.